# Is it safe to abbreviate \begin{foo}...\end{foo} with something like \bfoo ... \efoo

Tags: environments

Can I safely do this:

```
\newcommand\bfoo{\begin{foo}}
\newcommand\efoo{\end{foo}}
```

where `foo` is a standard LaTeX environment? Probably the `verbatim` environment breaks, but others as well? That way one could write

```
\bfoo
inside the foo environment
\efoo
```

instead of the longer

```
\begin{foo}
inside the foo environment
\end{foo}
```

I'd appreciate a technical statement, not a "I wouldn't do this, because it is unreadable". For a fact, I just want to know its implications and I wouldn't do this, because I think it is not very readable.

Comment: i don't know whether you consider the multi-line display environments of `amsmath` to be "standard", but those, like `verbatim`, require an exact match for the `\end{...}` component.  this is at least partly because of the multi-pass mechanism used for measuring the contents, required for proper placement; the details are complicated, but i think they are explained sufficiently (if not with total clarity) in the file `amsmath.dtx` (`texdoc -l amsmath` and choose `amsmath.pdf`).  however, `equation`, being a "basic" environment, *can* be abbreviated as you describe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say, anything based on finding the `\end{foo}` construct will fail. That includes any verbatim-like, which includes for example `beamer`'s `frame` environment, but also some of the AMS math environments such as `align`.

A second issue is space skipping, as

```
\begin{foo}
inside the foo environment
\end{foo}
```

has a space before `inside` which the `\bfoo` version does not include. You might feel that is no bad thing, but it is changing how the interface works. (Note: some environments deliberately `\ignorespaces` at the start, and this won't apply, for example `lrbox`.)

Answer (score 16):

There are many cases, where this shortcuts can be used, but
in general it is not safe.

**Body collectors**

Prominent example is package `amsmath`. It has the feature that in its displayed
equation environments (gather, align, ...) the handling of the equation number is
improved. The number moves down instead of clashing with the equation. But for this
purpose `amsmath` needs to know the width of the equation. Therefore it defines
macro `\collect@body` that looks for `\end` in the parameter text to dig through
the inner nested environments to find the right `\end` that closes the environment.

```
\def\collect@@body#1\end#2{...}% the relevant internal
```

Therefore `\end` must be visible at the same level and not hidden inside macros,
aliases or groups. However the `\begin` part is not affected, thus it can
be used for a definition:

```
\newcommand{\bfoo}{}
\def\bfoo#1\efoo{\begin{foo}#1\end{foo}}
```

Now, `\end{foo}` is visible for the code in `\begin{foo}`.
Disadvantage of this method that proper nesting is problematic:

```
\bfoo ... \bfoo ... \efoo ... \efoo
```

The first `\bfoo` would find the first `\efoo`, not the correct last `\efoo`.
Workaround:

```
\bfoo ... {\bfoo ... \efoo} ... \efoo
```

Package `environ` makes the method of `amsmath` available as standalone package.

**Verbatim**

Environments that process their body with changed catcodes, mostly because they
do not want that the macros and commands in the body gets executed. In case of
verbatim they should print unchanged. But this also affects the end macro,
that is read as seqence of characters and it is not build and called as macro
token. This includes `\end{...}`. The `verbatim` environment solves this by
looking for the sequence of characters `\`, `e`, `n`, `d`, `{`, `v`, … 
as end marker. Therefore something like `\efoo` is not detected.

Package `verbatim` uses a slightly different method, it scans line by line
and collects token until it finds the string `\end` with the matching
environment name in it.