# What is wrong with defining \bal as \begin{align}?

Tags: environments, amsmath, align

I'm trying to define two commands `\bal` and `\eal` instead of inserting `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` in my document, but in the code below, I'll get some errors. What is wrong with it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\bal}{%
 \begingroup
 \align%
\@ifstar{\nonumber}{}%
 }
 \newcommand{\eal}{\endalign\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\bal*
x=y
\eal
‎\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot, `align` literally looks for `\end{align}`. In general it is a bad idea to write using shortcuts like these as it makes the code much harder to read.

Comment: It has no sense to use `align` for a one line display; use `equation`, instead. Those shorthands *may* seem useful, but they aren't: they make the LaTeX document less readable and searchable. Good editors provide keyboard shortcuts that make easy inputting those environments.

Comment: Related questions (possible duplicates?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3169/86, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65581/86

Comment: @egreg my code above is just a MWE. My problem is that why this definition works for, say, `equation` environment, but doesn't work for `align` environment.

Comment: They are different beasts

Comment: @daleif: [You _can_](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5652), but I agree that you _shouldn't_.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The ‘problem’ is known and documented. I don't believe it's a problem at all, actually, for I can't see how

```
\bal
a&=b\\
c&<d
\eal
```

is clearer input than

```
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
c&<d
\end{align}
```

To the contrary, I firmly believe that the latter syntax is much better than the former, because it clearly marks the document. Good editors provide fast shortcuts for inputting the latter syntax with as few keystrokes as possible.

Let's see *why* your definition doesn't work. The `align` environment must absorb all of its contents before starting to typeset it, since it needs to do two passes over the material: the first pass is for measuring it, the second one for doing the real typesetting. This is the key for proper placement of the material *and* of the equation numbers.

With  `\newcommand{\bal}{\begingroup\align\@ifstar{\nonumber}{}}` you start `align`, but LaTeX will never see the end of it, because it doesn't expand tokens while absorbing the material, so `\eal` will be absorbed and not recognized as the end of `align`.

You *could* define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bal}{\@ifstar{\@bals}{\@bal}}
\def\@bals#1\eal{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}
\def\@bal#1\eal{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
\makeatletter
```

so that the required tokens are found, but it's clumsy and, as I said, it doesn't provide no benefit whatsoever, while obfuscating the code.

The issue doesn't show with `equation`, because this environment doesn't do complex tasks for measuring its contents. But the same arguments apply: there's no gain in inputting

```
\beq
a=b
\eeq
```

instead of

```
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
```

and nobody will ever be able to convince me of the contrary.

Similarly, one can't define a new environment based on `align` by

```
\newenvironment{myalign}
  {<something>\begin{align}}
  {\end{align}}
```

where `<something>` is any code one wants to be executed for modifying `align`'s behavior. The problem is exactly the same; but this will work:

```
\newenvironment{myalign}
  {<something>\align}
  {\endalign}
```

because `\align` captures the current environment's name and will use `\end{myalign}` as the end mark for the material to be gathered.

Comment: I would say: you give too much opinion; just answer the question. However, one should not say such things to rep 700k, should one? I will say this: I think OP's question more reasonable than you do.

Comment: @thb I gave the reason why it doesn't work and provided a workaround, didn't I?

Comment: True. You gave the reason and provided a workaround. Moreover, the workaround displays a level of skill I wish I possessed.

Answer (score 20):

This issue is dicussed in section **6** of the file `technote.pdf` among the files distributed with `amsmath.sty`. (on my system `texdoc technote.pdf` will open this file in a pdf viewer.)

I copy here the end of this section, but you should read it in full.

> Some workarounds:
>
> 1. `\def\bal#1\eal{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}`
> 2. Define `\newcommand{\env}[2]{\begin{#1}#2\end{#1}}` and then use
>      `\env{align}{...}`