# Changing inline math symbols throughout a whole document

Tags: math-mode, errors, inline

I have a document at hand that was written by using an old template and now I want to copy it to a new one. However, when I do this and execute the code I am facing the error

> Missing `$` inserted.

for all inline math modes. That's because in my initial template I used the symbol `\( \)` to write all the inline math equations and somehow my new template does not accept this notation but forces me to use `$` instead. So, my question is: **What should I do to define the equality `$...$ = \(...\)` or how can I interchange these two?**

Comment: By help -- "find/replace" function -- of used LaTeX editor?

Comment: try `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: For me `\(` and `\)`  are working, no matter what I try. Please provide MWE, so we can figure out, where the problem is.

Comment: @Zarko it will be painful to use it through all the document, what I am looking is actually a preamble code that interchanges these two symbols, if possible.

Comment: @touhami I am using this package already.

Comment: You could try `\renewcommand{\(}{$}` and `\renewcommand{\)}{$}`... But without MWE it's just guessing.

Comment: @sahin, well, use editor to do work for you, this should not be so painful. Just two its passes through your document without of any your intervention? Anyway, you have many other suggestion, what to do. Myself I will use editor for this job.

Comment: try `\makeatletter\DeclareRobustCommand\({%
  \relax\ifmmode\@badmath\else$\fi}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\){%
  \relax\ifmmode\ifinner$\else\@badmath\fi\else \@badmath\fi}\makeatother` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: excuse me, do you think it good template?

Comment: Sorry for being silent so long, I was trying to put my template into ShareLaTeX which I finally managed. Here it is: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5623f19368d179c93909d251

Comment: Ok, so the problem is certainly caused by `\def\({\left(}` and `\def\){\right)}`. I think you should change those in order to get back the usual `\(` and `\)` behaviour.

Comment: It is definitely not a good template. It is using obsolete and deprecated packages. It is loading things in the wrong order. It is loading things multiple times. It is setting manually what would be better managed by a package designed for the purpose. And it redefines the standard markup for inline maths mode!! At the very least, delete lines 59 and 60. Better, don't use it at all.

Comment: `epsfig`, `subfigure` are obsolete and ought not be used. Page layout dimensions: use `geometry` or a similar package rather than manual settings.  Tow letter font switches are 20+ years deprecated and ought not be used in LaTeX code. Font switches do not take an argument. Almost never should `\centerline` be used in current LaTeX.  Setting `\parskip` by hand is bad. If you really need this, use `parskip`.  Don't use maths mode for text superscripts - there are better ways these days. If you must change the line spread, use `setspace`.

Comment: Also, `eqnarray` shouldn't be used. Use `align` from amsmath instead.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean to edit it. I changed it without thinking. Why on earth did it let me?

Comment: Thanks @Wamseln, now I see the reason of the error, I'll accept it as an answer if you post.

Comment: @cfr, I'm not an expert in these things. I borrowed the code from one of my colleagues and didn't examined it deeply. Your comments are valuable. I will keep them as a side note for now and try to understand them for the future reference. Thanks for sparing time to write so long, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an attempt to clean things up a bit. More could be done, but I think this modifies the worst features of the original template.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% \usepackage{subfigure}% obsolete! use subfig or, better, subcaption
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newlength\normalparindent
\setlength\normalparindent\parindent
\usepackage{parskip,setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage[textwidth = 6.5in, textheight = 8.5in, marginparwidth=0pt, marginparsep=0pt, headheight=0pt, headsep=0pt, left=1in, top=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{{}}
\definecolor{MyDarkBlue}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.45}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=MyDarkBlue,
  linkcolor=MyDarkBlue,
  urlcolor=MyDarkBlue,
  pdfauthor={John Smith},
  pdftitle={SUBJECT},
  pdfsubject={hep-th}
}

% use align rather than eqnarray
\newcommand{\nn}{\nonumber}

\newcommand{\gmu}{\gamma^\mu}
\newcommand{\gnu}{\gamma^\nu}
\newcommand{\glmu}{\gamma_\mu}
\newcommand{\gf}{\gamma^5}
\newcommand{\Tr}{\text{Tr}}
\newcommand{\qb}{\mathbf{q}}
\newcommand{\pb}{\mathbf{p}}
\newcommand{\kb}{\mathbf{k}}
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\pd}{(2\pi)^d}
\newcommand{\intx}{\int d^d \mathbf{x}\ }

\newcommand{\la}{\langle}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}
\newcommand{\lb}{\left[}
\newcommand{\rb}{\right]}
\newcommand{\half}{\frac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\pf}{(2\pi)^4}
\newcommand{\intkd}{\int \frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D}\ }
\newcommand{\intpd}{\int \frac{d^Dp}{(2\pi)^D}\ }
\newcommand{\intpdo}{\int \frac{d^{D-1}k}{(2\pi)^{D-1}}\ }
\newcommand{\intl}{\int \frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\ }
\newcommand{\intld}{\int \frac{d^dl}{(2\pi)^d}\ }
\newcommand{\intle}{\int \frac{d^4l_E}{(2\pi)^4}\ }
\newcommand{\intp}{\int d^d \mathbf{p}\ }
\newcommand{\wsp}{\omega_{\mathbf{p}}}
\newcommand{\intpp}{\int \frac{d^d \mathbf{p}}{\sqrt{\pd 2\wsp}}\ }

\title{SUBJECT\thanks{This is a title.}}
\author{John Smith\textsuperscript{\itshape a,}\thanks{E-mail address: \Comment{\href{mail@mail.edu}}{\url{mail@mail.edu}}}}
\date{}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}% Note that your original settings do not get bold small-caps and would not do so even if this shape existed in bold for this font. If you want small-caps, change \bfseries to \scshape
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 10mm}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\large\scshape}
\postauthor{\par\end{center}\vskip 10mm}
\predate{}
\postdate{}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\begin{center}\itshape\textsuperscript{a}Department,\par Address\par\end{center}\vskip 10mm}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent\normalparindent% Not at all clear this is wise with skip between paragraphs as well, but if you must, you must...
\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes in here.
\end{abstract}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Introduction}

\section{Conclusions}

\section{Acknowledgements}

\appendix

\section{Appendix 1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\input{references.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image: Modified template]

Comment: `\be`,`\ee` etc. with `align` wont work, see [What is wrong with defining \bal as \begin{align}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100138)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! I forgot about Bernard's comment until I'd pasted the code and didn't check it out properly. Thanks for pointing that out, and for the link. (I'm sure I've read that before but had forgotten.)