# how to simple \begin{array} using \def?

Tags: macros

I want use `\def` to simplify the `\begin{array}`. Here is the code

```
\def\ba#1{\begin{array}#1}
\def\ea{\end{array}}

$$ \ba{ccc} a11 & a12 & a13\\ a21 & a22 & a23 \ea $$
```

I got error. I try to use:

```
\renewcommand {\begin{array}} {\ba}
\renewcommand {\end{array}} {\ea}
```

and this:

```
\newcommand(\ba)[]{\begin{array}}
\newcommand(\ea)[]{\end{array}}
```

get error too. So which command I should use?

It is different with programming language I think. Here I want just text substitute `\ba` instead `\begin{array}`.  It don't need evaluate in macro define.

**Update:** So I using the same tips to continue simpling:

```
\bea
 y &=& x^4 + 4      \nonumber \\
   &=& (x^2+2)^2 -4x^2 \nonumber \\
   &\le&(x^2+2)^2
\eea
```

It work fine. while combine them all:

```
\newcommand{\sev}[1]{\left| {#1} \right|}
\def\ba#1{\begin{array}{#1}}
\def\ea{\end{array}}
\def\bea{\begin{eqnarray}}
\def\eea{\end{eqnarray}}

Q: $$D=\sev{\ba{cccccc}
 s_0&s_1&s_2&\cdots&s_{n-1}&1\\ 
 s_1&s_2&s_3&\cdots&s_n&x\\ 
 s_2&s_3&s_4&\cdots&s_{n+1}&x^2\\ 
 \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 
 s_n&s_{n+1}&s_{n+2}&\cdots&s_{2n-1}&x^n \ea}$$ 
 and $s_k=x_1^k+x_2^k+\cdots+x_n^k$.

A: $$ \bea D &=& \sev{\ba{ccccc} 
 1&1&\cdots&1&1\\
 x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n&x\\ 
 \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\ 
 x_1^{n-1}&x_2^{n-1}&\cdots&x_n^{n-1}&x^{n-1}\\ 
 x_1^n&x_2^n&\cdots&x_n^n&x^n \ea} \eea $$
```

The `Q` is right, But the `A` is wrong and tell **"Missing \endgroup"**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Already done. :-)

Comment: Update the problem. `\sev`, `\ba`, '\bea' work fine alone. But combine them together got error.

Comment: **You cannot do this with math delimiting environments like `eqnarray`!** You actually shouldn't do this at all. I have never understood why people consider the 20 extra strokes for environments a problem. It takes hours to think out the contents, and then a couple seconds is a problem? And if it is, you should really rather get a TeX editor capable of good auto-complete. Last but not least, note that you hide the document's structure in the code. As a copy editor, I can tell you that dealing with a code like that is then really painful.

Comment: The problem you describe in your update under "A" has *nothing* to do with the abbreviations you've. Instead, it occurs because you're trying to initiate an `eqnarray` after an opening `$$` directive. Remove the `$$` directives in the "A" portion of the code and it will compile fine.

Comment: @Mico If I want keep $$. what can I do?

Comment: Another comment: Why on earth are you trying to use an `eqnarray` environment?! This environment is *severely deprecated* -- there is simply *no excuse* for using it these days. See the posting [eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) for more information on this subject.

Comment: @jiamo - You should *not* use `$$` in a LaTeX document; use `\[` and `\]` instead. No exceptions. By all means, do learn how to use the `align` environment.

Comment: Ok. By the way. After remove `$$` , and using `\def\bea{\begin{align}}` it can work like `\def\bea{\begin{eqnarray}}`

Comment: @jiamo - No it won't -- at least not the way you say you're going. More specifically, `\bea` will work, but `\def\eea{\end{align}} will not. See the posting [What is wrong with defining \bal as \begin{align}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100138/5001), and especially egreg's answer, for information on why `\eea`, as defined by you in the preceding comment, will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
\def\ba#1{\begin{array}#1}
```

to

```
\def\ba#1{\begin{array}{#1}}
```

Observe the pair of curly braces around `#1` in the second line of code.

Incidentally, you shouldn't use `$$` directly in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate displaymath mode; use `\[` and `\]` instead. For more information on this subject, see the postings [Why is [ ... ] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between $$, [, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)