# Renew command for \begin{equation}

Tags: macros, equations, environments

Since I am lazy, and I don't want to write

```
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
```

all the time, I thought I could have renewed the command into

```
\renewcommand\beq{\begin{equation}}
\renewcommand\enq{\end{equation}}
```

but I failed.

Why? Does someone know how to do it properly?

Comment: with the standard definition that should work, but is usually considered to be a bad idea as it greatly obscures the document structure. If you have loaded `amsmath` then it is explicitly documented that you can not replace the environments by command forms. (although you presumably would use `\newcommand` not `\renewcommand` unless those names have been defined previously)

Comment: Can't you make (or don't you have) shortcuts in your editor?

Comment: @Bernard mm you mean something like when you start writing a command and it does auto complete it?

Comment: Since `\beq` is not defined, you should use `\newcommand`. But ***don't***, you'll soon regret having done it and having littered your document with obscure markup.

Comment: @egreg I guess you are right.. The fact is that the (wrong) code $$ was so cute! Then I found out that is an aberration, and the correct command is \[ and \]. I just wondered if there is something similar to enumerate equations... But still, I guess I won't create new commands :D

Comment: @Alan Turing: Yes, or a shortcut that displays the whole environment, and the cursor in between. Most of them are able to do such thinds.

Comment: for the ams versions see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100138/what-is-wrong-with-defining-bal-as-beginalign

Comment: @Bernard Oh yes I have them! xD Indeed it's enough to write \begin{e and it does complete. Then by pushing enter I gain the \end{equation} for free. Not the bad indeed.

Comment: Its better to configure your editor to insert the `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` for you (I just type `eq<tab>` using [snippets](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-snippets) in vim). Using macro short-hands when you collaborate isn't really possible and journals don't like them either. If you intend to never show you documents to anyone else, and always work alone, this is of course fine.

Answer (score 5):

While the code you showed works without problems, provided you use `\newcommand` rather than `\renewcommand`, I can't recommend doing so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\beq{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand\enq{\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

\beq
a=b
\enq

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why do I recommend the fully spelled out version? There are several reasons, but here are the main ones.

1. `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` can easily become `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` for the unnumbered version (and conversely
2. You can look for environment nesting without distinguishing special cases
3. The code with explicit `\begin` and `\end` tag is more prominent when skimming through the typescript
4. Such shorthands cannot be used for `align` and the other `amsmath` display environments.

Littering a typescript with obscure markup is *a bad thing*. Really. Laziness can be implemented through the shortcuts provided by your text editor: every text editor provides them or, at least, a way to define new ones.

Personally, I don't even use shortcuts: typing `\begin{equation}` is as easy as remembering a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have personnaly used for years:

```
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\eneq}{\end{equation}}
```

Comment: Look at the comment with the most upvotes by our highest ranking user. You should not do this.