# Create a command using a `tasks` environment

Tags: macros, tasks

I would like to use a command `bitcol` (see below) with a `tasks` environment, but the following code give an error. How can I fix it ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\NewTasksEnvironment[style=itemize,label=\faCaretRight]{itcol}[\item]
%
\newcommand{\bitcol}[1][2]{\begin{itcol}(#1)}
\newcommand{\eitcol}{\end{itcol}}
%
\begin{document}

% OK
\begin{itcol}(3)
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4 
\end{itcol}

% KO
\bitcol[3]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4 
\eitcol

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question: [environments - What is wrong with defining \bal as \begin{align}? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100138/what-is-wrong-with-defining-bal-as-beginalign?noredirect=1&lq=1) (which I supposed is linked to in some deleted answer or something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *cannot* work this way. In order to do its job, the defined `itcol` environment has to *explicitly* see `\end{itcol}`.

I see no real reason to type

```
\bitcol[3]
...
\eitcol
```

instead of

```
\begin{itcol}(3)
...
\end{itcol}
```

If your aim is to use a standard optional argument, you can do as follows. But don't use the not recommended way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\NewTasksEnvironment[style=itemize,label=\faCaretRight]{itcolinner}[\item]

\NewDocumentEnvironment{itcol}{O{2}+b}
 {\begin{itcolinner}(#1)#2\end{itcolinner}}
 {}

%%% this part is for the not recommended way
\NewDocumentCommand{\bitcol}{O{2}}{\dobitcol{#1}}
\newcommand{\dobitcol}{}% for safety
\def\dobitcol#1#2\eitcol{\begin{itcolinner}(#1)#2\end{itcolinner}}
%%% end of code for the not recommended way

\begin{document}

% recommended way
\begin{itcol}[3]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4 
\end{itcol}

% NOT RECOMMENDED WAY
\bitcol[3]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4 
\eitcol

\end{document}
```

[image]