# flalign does not work in a newenvironment

Tags: align, environments

I have the following:

```
\newenvironment{examplebox}[1]{
    \begin{flalign*}
}
{
    \end{flalign*}
}

\begin{examplebox}{Test}
    & \lim_{x \to 2} f(x)
\end{examplebox}
```

This results in the following two errors:

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{examplebox} on input line 47 ended by \end{document}.
LaTeX Error: \begin{flalign*} on input line 47 ended by \end{examplebox}
```

The environment works fine if I put the flalign in the environment everytime I \begin it. However, I want this to be in a \newenvironemnt because I want to add styling around it and have it be easily reproducable every time I need it. Additionally, I have not decided a style for it because I am focuing more on the content of my document, so I want to be able to change it once and have it change all instances of it.

Is there any particular reason for this error, or is this just a restriction of flalign. If it is a restriction, then are there are alternatives for it?

Comment: Probably caused by [environments - What is wrong with defining \bal as \begin{align}? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100138/what-is-wrong-with-defining-bal-as-beginalign), but also try [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: actually the other one a bit difficult because of the `*`

Comment: The command is supposed to have a parameter. I don't see #1 anywhere in the code. Is the first parameter optional or compulsory?

Comment: @S.Venkataraman It is in the code, but I removed it for this question. Nevertheless, the errors are the same either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common problem with `amsmath` alignments. You *might* do

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{examplebox}[1]{%
  % do something with #1
  \start@align\tw@\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}
{\endalign}
\makeatother
```

but it's simpler to use `ltcmd` (formerly `xparse`):

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{examplebox}{mb}{%
  % do something with #1
  \begin{flalign*}#2\end{flalign*}%
}{}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! May I ask what the "mb" means and how I might go about a third (with the second being optional) argument?

Comment: @Eshy `m` means a mandatory argument, `b` means the environment's content. See `texdoc usrguide`.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help!